# Adding and calculating new variables as rows in R-studio

Tags: r, variables, regression, mutate

I'm a beginner in R-studio. I have a list in long format with collected data variables regarding 312 companies. From this data I want to calculate new variables and add them as rows, not columns. For example total debt / total assets for all companies as a new variable. I can only seem to find the way to add and caluclate new variables as columns but I need the format to be long format, not wide. The end goal is to conduct a multivariable regression.

Here is a link of the data structure in Excel. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNx96.jpg. The RIC is the company ID. So it's all the variables for one company, one at a time.

Thank you so much in advance.

I relied on multiple YouTube videos and websites. I've read about the mutate function but can't figure out how to add new variable as rows in the correct place rather than columns.

Comment: `rbind` of base R and `bind_rows` of package dplyr might be useful. `bind_rows` is not as picky about the order of corresponding columns.

Answer (score 0):

Let there be companies named by numbers in our first column, FCC codes in the second column and values in the third column:

```r
example <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, 3),
                      fcc = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3),
                      data = round(rnorm(9, 1000, 200), 2))
print(example)
#>   id fcc    data
#> 1  1   A  931.25
#> 2  2   A  422.73
#> 3  3   A 1283.94
#> 4  1   B 1013.70
#> 5  2   B 1056.49
#> 6  3   B 1130.90
#> 7  1   C  734.10
#> 8  2   C  819.83
#> 9  3   C 1326.22
```

If I understand you correctly, you want the sum for all fcc == "A" and for all fcc == "B" and all fcc == "C".
There is the function `aggregate` for this:

```r
aggregate(data ~ fcc, data = example, FUN = sum)
#>   fcc    data
#> 1   A 3286.13
#> 2   B 3083.45
#> 3   C 2770.15
```

I see no reason, and I advise against, adding that to the original data frame. These are inherently different data. The raw data are one thing, the aggregated data another thing so putting both in the same columns is against how you should use R data frames. It sounds like something people might do in spreadsheets (e.g., MS Excel) but that does not turn it into a good idea. As @I_O wrote in his comment: there is `rbind` for that but I am not going to demonstrate that.